# convert wide-character string read with wscanf to an integer in C

Tags: c, string, integer, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a string read using wscanf to an integer using wcstol, both from header file wchar.h on Linux. While wcstol works on constant wide-char strings (e.g. L"23") it does not work on wscanf input, which puzzles me. I always get 0, even if the input is actually numeric (e.g. 23). Why?

```
$ ./test 
23
s=23
0
```

Here is my test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main() {
  wchar_t s[100];
  if (wscanf(L"%s", s) == 1) {
    wprintf(L"s=%s\n", s);
    wprintf(L"%ld\n", wcstol(s, NULL, 10));
  }
}
```

If instead of wcstol I use strtol, it works but I get this warning:

/usr/include/stdlib.h:183:17: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘wchar_t * {aka int *}’

which I could silent using a type cast. I thought wcstol was the right way to parse a wide-char string to an integer. Since on my machine chars are actually ints, strtol happens to work, but that leaves me still unsure whether this is the right solution. What's going on here? Why wcstol does not do its job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with the `wscanf()` format.  A `%s` field descriptor designates a pointer to `char`, just like for `scanf()`.  These two functions differ a bit in how they convert the input, but they agree on the meaning of the field descriptors.

For reading into an array of `wchar_t`, you want `%ls`.  Moreover, whether you should use `wscanf()` of `scanf()` is primarily a function of how the input is encoded, *not* of the data type into which you want to scan its contents.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the `wscanf` format.

As described on [MAN](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwscanf.3p.html):

> **s**
>
> Matches a sequence of non white-space wide characters. [...] The application shall ensure that the corresponding argument is a pointer to a character array large enough to accept the sequence and the terminating null character, which shall be added automatically.

Simply "%s" must be used for non-wide-chars string, as usual in `printf`, `scanf` and so on

[MAN](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwscanf.3p.html) also says:

> **l (ell)**
>
> Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, X, or n conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to long or unsigned long; [...] that a following c, s, or [ conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to wchar_t.

That means you must use `"%ls"` as format string to read a wide-char string.

There is another **non-standard ISO C** solution if you are on [POSIX](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wscanf) or on [.NET MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272895(v=vs.60).aspx): format `"%S"` can be used.

Comment: There is no uppercase `S` type specifier. This might be a non-standard extension.

Comment: @Olaf it is on [POSIX Programmer's manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wscanf) and [.NET MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/9y6s16x1.aspx) support it.

Comment: Maybe, but that is likely a legacy from pre-C11 or C99. Better use the most common standard, which is C.

Comment: @Olaf, LPs, for what it's worth, the [POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fwscanf.html) indeed do document `%S` as a synonym for `%ls`.  They also explicitly mark it as an extension to standard C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, LPs: The question is not tagged POSIX. Please remember this read by other beginners who might wounder `%S` does not work. It would be a really good idea to at least have a note in the answer (or remove it as obsolete legacy). That's all I wanted.

Comment: @Olaf, of course.  You are right call out the fact that the `S` field code is not in standard ISO C.  I am simply attempting to clarify for the same inexperienced programmers you mention that that is the sense in which it is "non-standard", since POSIX is a standard, too.  And also, perhaps, to point out that not every C feature in the POSIX standard (or in any vendor's documentation) is a feature of ISO C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I just see the next question pop up: "Why does `%S` not work". Of course not with such a clear description. There are a lot of non-POSIX systems (and non-Windows or OS-X)in the wild. Problem is comments are not that often read (are they indexed by google?). Anyway, let's settle this, LPs seems not to be in the mood of clarifying and the accepted answer is clear...

Comment: @Olaf I was abroad and edititing this answer with my smartphone it was not a good idea. I edited to clarify...I hope ;)